# How to fit a periodic trend in 2d data in R?

Tags: r, spatial, data-fitting, trend

I used the lm(..poly(..)) functionality in R to remove a large scale spatial trend (slope) in my elevation data (see image below).

The detrended data shows a new, periodic trend of rills and gullies. I want to remove this trend as well, but only in the direction of the rills and gullies. Is there a way in which I can use a directional sine or cosine function to fit this periodic trend?

[image: Image of my detrended data]

Comment: The data looks as if it could be broken down to sines and cosines of x, entirely. The 8th degree polynomial might not be necessary. You might be able to break the data down using a fourier transformation.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your suggestion. Do you know which functionality I could use to achieve this?